# Selenium - looking for examples of converting xpath locators to css

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I have a ton of tests written in xpath that I need to convert to css.

I don't want to use an automation tool as I want to take the opportunity to learn the way to do things using the css approach in selenium.

Where can I find examples of 'before' and 'after' when changing from xpath to css for locators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've answered it yourself, but I swear by this site, has a very nice diagram showing you exactly what you are asking:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Answer (score 1):

Here are 30 examples of 'before' and 'after' xpath to css:

Note that css also uses 0 based positioning and xpath uses 1 based, as in:

Example:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]
css=li#topic_roles_input input[type=checkbox]:nth(0)
```

---

The list:

```
//ul[contains(@id,'district-switcher')]//li/ul/li[4]/a
css=ul#district-switcher li > ul > li:nth(3) > a

//ul[contains(@id,'district-switcher')]//a[contains(text(),'District Management Council')]
css=ul#district-switcher a:contains('District Management Council')

//ul[contains(@id,'district-switcher')]//a[contains(text(),'${QA_run_number}')]
css=ul#district-switcher a:contains('${QA_run_number}')

//h3[contains(@id,'active-district')]
css=h3#active-district

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Calendar')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains("Calendar")

//tr[1]//td[contains(@class,'starts_on')]
css=tr td.starts_on

//tr[1]//td[contains(@class,'ends_on')]
css=tr td.ends_on

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Schools')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains('Schools')

//table[contains(@id, 'schools')]//tbody//tr//td/a
css=table#schools tbody tr td a

//a[contains(text(),'6DAYERS')]
css=a:contains('6DAYERS')

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Students')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(Students)

//body//td[contains(text(),'QA-001')]
css=td:contains('QA-001')

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Roles')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(Roles)

//table//tr//td[contains(text(),"Language Therapist")]
css=table tr td:contains(LanguageTherapist)

//table//tr//td[contains(text(),"Speech Therapist")]
css=table tr td:contains(Speech Therapist )

//table//tr//td[contains(text(),"DELETE_ME")]
css=table tr td:contains(DELETE_ME)

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Activities')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(activities)

xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"][1])
css=li#activity_roles_input input[@type="checkbox"]:nth(0)

//table[contains(@id,'activities')]//tr//td[contains(text(),"Activity001")]
css=table#activities tr td:contains("Activity001")

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Practitioners')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(Practitioners)

//table//tr//td[contains(text(),'mdurrant+${QA_run_number}_001@dmcouncil.org')]
css=table tr td:contains(mdurrant+${QA_run_number}_001@dmcouncil.org)

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Topics')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(Topics)

xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'topic_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]
css=li#topic_roles_input input[type=checkbox]:nth(0)

//a[contains(text(),'Topic001')]
link=Topic001

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Settings')]
link=Settings

//ul[contains(@class,'home-menu')]//a[contains(text(),'Settings')]
css=ul.home-menu a:contains(Settings)

xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'setting_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]
css=li#setting_roles_input input[type=checkbox]:nth(0)

xpath=(//table/tbody/tr//td/a[contains(@class,'delete_link')])
table > tbody > tr td > a.delete_link

//td[contains(text(),'Setting001')]
css=td:contains('setting001')

//a[contains(text(),'Practitioners')]
css=a:contains(Practitioners)

//tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a@href
tr td:contains('6 Day'):nth(0) + td + td a[href]
```

Comment: FYI, there is no such CSS selector as `:contains()`.  It was an early proposal that was discarded years ago.  It won't work in Selenium.

Comment: Some software implements `:contains()` despite it's having been dropped from the CSS spec. Selenium IDE may allow it, but Selenium 2 (WebDriver) and Selenium RC do not.

Comment: hmmm, i've read that "the css2 contains function is not in css3, however selenium supports the superset of css 1,2 and 3."  Are you sure that the support is only in the IDE?

Comment: Nope, you're heard wrong.  The `:contains()` selector was never part of CSS2.  It was proposed in CSS3, but was removed before the 2005 last-call working draft.